# Set IsEnabled for nested LayoutGroup based on property of parent

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button, devexpress

I have a radio button control and some dependent controls that I would like to be enabled or disabled based on which radio button is selected.

To do this, I'm trying to bind `IsEnabled` on the `LayoutGroup`s with `{Binding IsSelected, ElementName=radioButtonControlName}`. It is not working though.

My XAML looks like this

```
<Grid>
    <dxlc:LayoutGroup Orientation="Horizontal">
        <dxe:ListBoxEdit ShowBorder="False" StyleSettings="{dxe:RadioListBoxEditStyleSettings}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <dxe:ListBoxEditItem Name="radioButtonA" IsSelected="{Binding IsASelected, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
                <dxlc:LayoutGroup>
                    <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="A">
                        <dxlc:LayoutGroup Name="aLayoutGroup" IsEnabled="{Binding IsSelected, ElementName=radioButtonA}">
                            <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Date A">
                                <dxe:DateEdit EditValue="{Binding DateA, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
                            </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                            <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Text A">
                                <dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{Binding TextA, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
                            </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                        </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
                    </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
            </dxe:ListBoxEditItem>
            <dxe:ListBoxEditItem Name="radioButtonB" IsSelected="{Binding IsASelected, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
                <dxlc:LayoutGroup>
                    <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="B">
                        <dxlc:LayoutGroup Name="bLayoutGroup" IsEnabled="{Binding IsSelected, ElementName=radioButtonB}">
                            <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Date B">
                                <dxe:DateEdit EditValue="{Binding DateB, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
                            </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                            <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Text B">
                                <dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{Binding TextB, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
                            </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                        </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
                    </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
            </dxe:ListBoxEditItem>
        </dxe:ListBoxEdit>
    </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
</Grid>
```

Incidentally, if I move the `LayoutGroup`s outside of the `ListBoxEdit` control, it works as expected. The problem then is that I don't know how to align the radio buttons with the dependent controls. If someone can help me align those properly, then that solution would work as well, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am not dynamically generating the radio buttons, I decided to not use a `ListBoxEdit` and instead just put `RadioButton` elements in my layout. I needed to change the `IsSelected` binding to `IsChecked`, but other than that it works pretty much the same way.